# Stop insertion of record in tabe if the start_date and end_date is bettween start_date and end_date php mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in which task is assigned to users with start date and end date. I want to do is check if a user is available for the task which he is being assigned mean check is their any task is assigned to him between the given date. If it is then restrict the user from added the record.

For example if the user is assigned task where `start_date is 23-06-2015` `end_date is 23-08-2015.` Then when i add new task with date between above start_date and end_date then it should return record with the below query. It is working for some records but for input like `start_date  23-06-2015` and `end_date 23-06-2015` it is not working.

Here is my Query for check availability if record found then return the record

```
SELECT t.*
FROM task t
INNER JOIN project p ON p.id = t.pid
INNER JOIN USER u ON u.uid = t.uid
INNER JOIN STATUS st ON st.id = t.id
WHERE t.uid = 6 AND (t.start_date BETWEEN  '2015-06-23' AND '2015-08-23'  OR t.end_date BETWEEN '2015-06-23' AND '2015-08-23') AND t.pid IN (
SELECT id
FROM project) AND st.status = 0 AND t.etype='task'
```

Comment: Sometimes I use `>=` and `<=` to compare the dates than using between. So it can detect the same date.

Comment: yes i have done that also but not working but i suppose  BETWEEN is alternative to >= <= in mysql but i have also done that @DrixsonOseña

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking availability of particular user( guessed by code `t.uid=6`), If so then refined query should be:

```
SELECT t.* FROM task t INNER JOIN project p ON p.id = t.pid
   INNER JOIN STATUS st ON st.id = t.id WHERE t.uid = 6 AND st.status=0 
   AND (t.start_date BETWEEN '2015-06-23' AND '2015-08-23' OR 
   t.end_date BETWEEN '2015-06-23' AND '2015-08-23') AND t.etype='task';
```

I just remove some redundancy in your query. And it should work, means it will return record(already assigned task to user-id-6), if task is present in `project` table with status=0, taskType='task' and clash with input dates.

Comment: it is not working if i give task s_date 2015-06-24 e_date 2015-07-31 then if we assign him task with date of s_date 2015-06-25 and e_date 2015-06-26 then it also save the record but should not save it. because he is already assigned a task in these date

Comment: @UsamaLucky: I understand your logic but in that case you need to show your insertion code also, in your question only select-existing-task part is there. _You need to put full code of your logic from analyzing availability to inserting task_. **Then only anybody can help.**